# Add leading space to certain values in a data frame

Tags: r

I have the following data frame and for each positive number (yes they are need to be stored as strings) I want to add a leading space.

```
d <- data.frame(c1 = c("4", "-1.5", "5", "-3"))

> d
    c1
1    4
2 -1.5
3    5
4   -3
```

So far I used grep and invert to return only the positive numbers which I want to add a leading space to:

```
d$c1[grep("-", d$c1, invert = TRUE)]
```

However, I am not sure how to proceed. I think I rather have to work with indices than with the actual number. And probably incorporate gsub? Is that right?

Comment: If you explain why you need that space, someone might suggest a better way to achieve your final goal.

Comment: Have you looked at `?sprintf` or `?formatC`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`paste(' ',d[d[,1] > 0,])` does that look like what you want?

Comment: yes that works. I just found that solution which adds the changes to the data frame. However you need to parse c1 to as.character first. The numbers where stored as factors and not as chars.  d$c1[grep("-", d$c1, invert = TRUE)] <- paste(" ", d$c1[grep("-", d$c1, invert = TRUE)]). Probably not the best solution but seems to work though :)

Answer (score 4):

Here is an approach using `formatC()`. Similar results could be achieved using `sprintf()`. Note that I don't just add a single space. instead this approach pads each string to a maximum width.

```
d <- data.frame(c1 = c("4", "-1.5", "5", "-3"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
d <- transform(d, d2 = formatC(c1, width = 4), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

R> d
    c1   d2
1    4    4
2 -1.5 -1.5
3    5    5
4   -3   -3
R> str(d)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ c1: chr  "4" "-1.5" "5" "-3"
 $ d2: chr  "   4" "-1.5" "   5" "  -3"
```

If you don't know ahead of time what the `width` argument should be, compute it from `d$c1`:

```
R> with(d, max(nchar(as.character(c1))))
[1] 4
```

Or use it directly inline

```
d <- transform(d, d2 = formatC(c1, width = max(nchar(as.character(c1)))),    
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: ah that's a very good solution too! I like the way it's done. great thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

The `print` method for `data.frame`s has nice automated padding features. In general, the strings are padded on the left with spaces to ensure right alignment (by default). You can take advantage of this by capturing the print output. For example, using your `d`:

```
> print(d, print.gap = 0, row.names = FALSE)
  c1
   4
-1.5
   5
  -3
```

The argument `print.gap = 0` ensures that there are no extra padding spaces in front of the longest string. `row.names = FALSE` prevents row names from being printed.

This case is special in a couple ways: The column name is shorter than the longest character string in the data, and the `data.frame` is only one column. To generalize, you could subset the data and `unname` it:

```
myChar <- unname(d[, 1, drop = FALSE])
```

Then, you can capture the `print`ed object using `capture.output`:

```
> (dStr <- capture.output(print(myChar, print.gap = 0, row.names = FALSE)))
[1] "  NA" "   4" "-1.5" "   5" "  -3"
```

Since the column name is also printed, you could subset the object thusly:

```
> dStr[-1]
[1] "   4" "-1.5" "   5" "  -3"
```

This way, you don't have to know how long the longest character string is, and this can handle most data types, not just character.